# How do I enable wifi before login on ubuntu-mate running on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Ubuntu-mate 1.20.1 (Ubuntu 18.04.2) that I want to run headless and use VNC and SSH to access.  Connections will be via WiFi, and the Pi has a static address on my network. Problem is, the WiFi isn't active until after I log in, and I can't log in without the WiFi being active!
How can I activate the WiFi after boot, but before anyone logs in?

Comment: your question is not related to the RPi ... it is a Linux question ... try asking here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver) 32 bit, Kernel Linux 4.15.0-1053-raspi2 armv7l, MATE 1.20.1 on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

The solution was to check the box next to 'All users may connect to this network".  It is found at Gear (upper right hand corner) => System Settings => Internet and Network => Network Connections => click on WiFi network => General => check "All users may connect to this network".

Doing this fixed the problem and allowed me to have access to log on over WiFi without a keyboard or monitor attached to the Raspberry Pi.  I am using TeamViewer to access the Raspberry Pi.  But, the problem was that the WiFi was not being enabled without logging on first otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of stuff, including installing all of the updates and changing things in the network manager, and now it seems to be working like it should.  I'm not sure what fixed it, but I suspect it was clicking the *All users may use this network* box, combined with one of the 2 hours worth of updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t set Ubuntu up without keyboard etc!

Ubuntu has no user account until you set it up.

Configuring Network Manager (assuming Ubuntu MATE still uses it ) from the command line is difficult, but can be done with nmcli.

Once setup it should work (I have done on 16.04)

You would be better to configure Debian networking or install dhcpcd.

Comment: You could mount the SD card on another linux host, chroot into the SD card, and setup either Network Manager, wpa supplicant or netplan. But if you don't know you could do that, it is unlikely you would know how to do that...

Comment: the OP is talking about running headless ... not setting up headless ... the OP is saying that networking does not come up before login ... sounds like the networking daemon is started by the user login scripts